# is datastore give the deleted keys again

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

when i delete an entity ,is it possibile that the datastore give the keys again?
In documents writing that the datastore never gives same key in same parent group.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Autogenerated keys will never be reused.